# Setting debug start external program option to an executable of a class library in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have a project that creates a new solution with one class library project. I want ***Debug Start external Program option*** of the class library of that solution to get set with an ***External Executable Application*** (not manually, should get populated at the time of solution creation).

I am unaware of libraries that do this task.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. This is not a place to ask for libraries, because libraries always lead to opinion-based answers. Have you tried to look into the Visual Studio project file format? It's XML, so there's hardly a need for a library to accomplish this task.

Comment: how can i accomplish the task programatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a `.csproj.user` file for the generated project. It's XML format. You can read and create XML using the [XmlDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Set `<StartAction>` to `Program` and set `<StartProgram>` to the executable of your choice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
    <StartProgram>myexecutable.exe</StartProgram>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Note that you can also put these properties directly into the .csproj file if you prefer.